# Lua value changing by itself?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm new to using both Lua and LOVE2D. I thought that a perfect way to get familiar with the tools would be to create a snake style game. currently I have most of the things up and running. I run into a problem when adding to the snake after it eats the food. My snake class currently consists of a table of cells, each cell has a gridX and gridY variable. I also have 2 global variable called lastGridX and lastGridY that keep track of the last position of the last cell in the snake class. I update the position of the cells in reverse order and set them equal to the position of the cell with 1 less index in the table. I update the first cell by just adding a constant value called SCALE, the size of each square on the grid, to it. My problem arises when the position of the position of the first cell is the same as the position of the food. For some reason my lastGridX and lastGridY also change to the x and y positions of the food even though I never change them myself. This makes it so that every cell has the same position which is obviously not what I want to happen. Any help would be appreciated thank you. Here is some of the code below.

```
function love.update(dt)
-- updates the snake's position in set intervals
moveTimer = moveTimer - dt
if moveTimer <= 0 then
    lastGridX = snake[#snake].gridX
    lastGridY = snake[#snake].gridY
    -- updates the body of the snake
    for i = #snake, 2, -1 do
        snake[i].gridX = snake[i - 1].gridX
        snake[i].gridY = snake[i - 1].gridY
    end

    -- updates the head of the snake
    if direction == "right" then
        snake[1].gridX = snake[1].gridX + SCALE
    elseif direction == "left" then
        snake[1].gridX = snake[1].gridX - SCALE
    elseif direction == "up" then
        snake[1].gridY = snake[1].gridY - SCALE
    elseif direction == "down" then
        snake[1].gridY = snake[1].gridY + SCALE
    end
    moveTimer = MOVE_TIMER_MAX
    print(lastGridX, lastGridY)
    print(snake[#snake].gridX, snake[#snake].gridY)
    if snake[1].gridX == newFood.gridX and snake[1].gridY == newFood.gridY then
        -- moves the food to a random location on the grid if it is eaten
        newFood.gridX = math.random(0, 63) * SCALE
        newFood.gridY = math.random(0, 35) * SCALE

        -- adds a new body part to the end of the snake 
        newC = cell
        newC.gridX = lastGridX
        newC.gridY = lastGridY
        print(lastGridX, lastGridY)
        print(snake[#snake].gridX, snake[#snake].gridY)
        os.execute("pause")
        table.insert(snake, newC)
    end
end
```

end

Comment: values don't change by themselves... what is cell? provide more code.

Comment: When declaring new variables, use `local`. At the moment all of your variables are global, so if any part of your program has variables that share the names of the variables in the `love.update` function, the variables will be shared. This could lead to seemingly random changes to their values.